# Should I always use a view model or is it ok to use ViewData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

when do you think is it better to use ViewData over a view model?

I have the same exact partial view in a couple of main views. I'd like to control how a partial view is rendered but I'd also prefer the partial view to accept only a view model which is a collection of records, just a pure `IEnumerable<>` object. I'd rather avoid to send the full view model object from a main view because it also contains a lot of different properties, objects, that control paging, sorting, filtering etc.

Therefore the question is if I should create another view model for the partial view or is it ok to use ViewData? I've read soemwhere that using `ViewData` is a very bad practice.

With View Data, I could simply pass require details like this:

```
@{
    ViewDataDictionary vd = new ViewDataDictionary
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,object>("WithDelete", Model.WithDelete),
        new KeyValuePair<string,object>("WithRadarCode", Model.WithCode)
    };
}

// ...

@if (Model != null) {
    Html.RenderPartial("_ListOfRecordingsToRender", Model.recordingViewModel, vd);
}
```

At the moment, it would be sorted out.

My worry is that currently this `*.recordingViewModel` has plenty of different variations in my project, because of different models for creating / editting,  listing, shoing details of a record etc. I feel like it may start to be too messy in my project if I make view model for each action.

What do you think. Please could you advice on that particular problem. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should stick to using a `ViewModel`, your `ViewModel` is the class that defines your requirements for the view.

My reason behind this is that in the long run, it will be a lot more maintainable. When using `ViewBag` it's a `dynamic` class so in your views you should be checking if the `ViewBag` property exists (And can lead to silly mistakes like typo's) e.g.:

```
if(ViewBag.PropertyName != null)
{
    // ViewBag.PropertyName is a different property to ViewBag.propertyName
}
```

This type of code can make your View's quite messy. If you use a strongly typed model, you should be able to put most of the logic in your controllers and keep the View as clean as possible which is a massive plus in my books.

You also will also end up (if you use `ViewBag`) attempting to maintain it at some point and struggle. You are removing one great thing about C#, it's a strongly typed language! `ViewBag` is not strongly typed, you may think you are passing in a `List<T>` but you could just be passing a `string`.

One last point, you also will lose out on any intellisense features in Visual Studio.

> I feel like it may start to be too messy in my project if I make view model for each action.

Wont it just be as messy in your controllers assigning everything to a `ViewBag`? If it was a `ViewModel` you could send it off to a 'Mapping' class to map your DTO to your View.

Instead of this:

```
// ViewModel
var model = new CustomViewModel()
{
    PropertyOne = result.FirstResult,
    PropertyTwo = result.SecondResult,
}
//ViewBag
ViewBag.PropertyOne = result.FirstResult;
ViewBag.PropertyTwo = result.SecondResult;
```

You could do this:

```
var mapper = new Map();
var model = mapper.MapToViewModel(result);
```

*You would obviously need to provide an implimentation to the mapping class, look at something like [`Automapper`](http://automapper.org/)

> I'd also prefer the partial view to accept only a view model which is a collection of records, just a pure IEnumerable<> object. I'd rather avoid to send the full view model object from a main view because it also contains a lot of different properties, objects, that control paging, sorting, filtering etc.

That is fine, just create a view model that has a property of `IEnumerable<T>`. In my opinion you should try and use a strongly typed `ViewModel` in all of your scenarios.

Comment: I agree. Using viewmodels, overall, is my favourite way also.

Comment: Good answer, viewmodels all the way.

Comment: ViewBag might be useful in some scenarios, but I would prefer to avoid it. You know as soon as you see `ViewBag` uses it's an instant code smell.

Comment: @JamieRees Hi. Thanks for a quick answer. OK i am going to change the code. I did not follow this: "you could send it off to a 'Mapping' class to map your DTO to your View". I don't understand what it means to map DTO and what 'mapping' is. I probably missing simething simple here ...