# Dynamically maintain standard maintenance pages for ASP.NET MVC 5 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dynamic

New to ASP.NET MVC, but I have been looking around for quite some time and thinking how to achieve dynamically generate views based on the model? I have spent quite number of days reading articles online but I get confused at the end of day, so decided to ask a question, please help (if possible)..

I have about **25+ maintenance tables that requires CRUD functionality**, so I wouldn't want to create + maintain 25 views and controllers.

It should be managed via a single controller and view based on the model supplied from Menu itself (as generics). How best to achieve this type of functionality?

Am pretty sure some of you have already implemented this type of functionality, it would be good if you share some insights?

Thanks in advance!
Yam

Comment: Any solution to this that I have thought is bad. This is not really suppose to be done in the way you want. You don't want to maintain 25 views right? But why would you want to maintain 1 massive controller and 1 massive view that will (I can grantee you) cause you maintainability issues? You don't need 25 controllers but depending on what you are doing you will most likely need more than 1. Also regarding your tag of `dynamic` read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647562/should-i-always-use-a-view-model-or-is-it-ok-to-use-viewdata/31647765#31647765 it's about dynamic views.

Comment: @JamieR: The controller shouldn't be massive at all. It should contain the standard ActionResults and ActionMethods (such as Create, View, Edit and Delete). The method parameters should differ based on Models, basically all those 25 maintenance pages will have their own models like Country, State, Product, Customer, Supplier, Part, PartType, PartGroup, etc.. Hope this make sense?

Comment: Maybe, we can use IoC in the methods of Controller to inject Models?